# Android parse - clean local data store after uninstalling or clear the app

Tags: android, parse-platform, local-datastore

I am having issue with cleaning my local data store after uninstalling or clear the app from settings. Can you tell me what I doing wrong ?

I want local data store to empty, once I clear the app or uninstall the app completely.

my application class:

```
  public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
//        ParseObject.registerSubclass(test.class);
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
        Parse.initialize(this, "xyz", "abc");
//        ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
      /* Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
                .applicationId("myappkey")
                .clientKey("myclientkey")
                .server("http://100.100.100.100:1000/parse/") // The trailing slash is important.
        .enableLocalDataStore().build()
        );*/
        ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
        defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
        ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
    }
```

Comment: After reviewing my entire code, I found out I added in my manifest file this permission. 

<application
        android:name="parse.definations.MyApplication"
        android:icon="@mipmap/my_icon"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme"
        >

Comment: This permission was not needed.

android:allowBackup="true"

due to which it was saving on Google cloud and restored next time the app was installed. I read it here:

[link](https://developer.android.com/training/backup/autosyncapi.html)